# Remove duplicates in one row but different columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe

Here is what my sample data look like:
[image]

I need to remove duplicate characters in column URL based on row. The expected result is like:
[image]

I know a loop can do the job, but wonder if there is easier way.

Comment: One not-so-efficient-way: `df[] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) replace(x, duplicated(x), "")))`

Answer (score 0):

```
# Install

# install.packages("dplyr")

# Load
# library("dplyr")
```

## use distinct() function

```
# like distinct(my_data)
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants